# Creating a list of lambdas in Python in a loop does not use the right number

Tags: python, numpy, function, for-loop, lambda

I want to create a list of sine functions using a for loop where the parameters depend on a list. As a minimum working example, let us say that my list is

```
lst = [0, 50, 75, 83, 98, 84, 32]
```

I want my loop to output the following list of functions:

```
[0, sin(50x), sin(75x), sin(83x), sin(98x), sin(84x), sin(32x)]
```

Here's what I tried:

```
function = [];
lst = [0, 50, 75, 83, 98, 84, 32]
for m in lst:
    function.append(lambda x : np.sin(m*x))
```

This does give me a list of 7 functions:

```
[<function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(x)>]
```

But when I evaluate `function[0](1)` it outputs `0.5514266812416906` whereas it should be 0 (m=0 implies sin(0*x) = sin(0) = 0 for all values of x), so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: This is one of the trickiest Python traps.  Your lambdas are capturing the NAME `m`, not the value.  When the loop ends, `m` is 32, so all the functions will use 32.  The trick is to capture the value as a default:  `lambda x, m=m: np.sin(m*x)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: this is not only tricky in Python, it's also tricky in C# for similar reason.

Comment: `for i in range(len(lst)):
    function.append(lambda x, m=lst[i]: np.sin(m * x))`